# Xamarin UIAlertView clicked - Opens new View

Tags: xamarin

just wondering basically i have an Azure authentication system that opens when clicking on a facebook button or twitter button it then asks to authenticate the app and once logged in displays a UIalertview with the options to click "OK" or "Cancel".

I was wondering how once they clicked ok i could get it to display the next View?
I know my uialertview is called alert - so was thinking it would alert.Clicked (); then something in there but not sure what.

Here is the method that is processing the login and the alertview if someone can get back to me fast.

```
private void DoLogin(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider)
    {
        var task =  this.client.LoginAsync(this, provider).ContinueWith(t => {
            MobileServiceUser user = t.Result;

            this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("Logged In!", string.Format ("Hello user {0}", user.UserId),
                    null, "OK", new string[] {"Cancel"});
                alert.Clicked();
                alert.Show ();



            });
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you could do this:

```
alert.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
{
    // check if the user NOT pressed the cancel button
    if (args.ButtonIndex != alert.CancelButtonIndex)
    {
        // present your next UIViewController, something like this
        NavigationController.PushViewController(new YourNextViewController(), true);
    }
};
```

For more information about UIAlertView check out it's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html

Comment: This did not work.. Just send it back to the Login screen hmm.. any other suggestions?

Comment: Its fine fixed this now :)